# How to have a dark theme MUI table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, darkmode

I have a Table component from MUI but I am not able to convert it into dark theme.
I used `styled()` to create a custom dark theme table and even used `sx` prop to make it dark but none of these two methods worked.
We can see how ugly table is looking. How to have a proper dark theme table without making it more complicated:

[image]

```
<TableContainer component={Paper} variant="primary"
    sx={{
      backgroundColor:'primary.main',
      color:'white'
    }}
    >
      <Table aria-label="simple table" variant="primary" 
      sx={{
        color:'white',
        backgroundColor:'primary.main'
      }}
      >
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Activity</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Tokens</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Amount</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Date</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">txn</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row) => (
            <TableRow
              key={row.tokens}
              sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
            >
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.activity}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.tokens}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.amount}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.date}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.txn}</TableCell>
              {/* <TableCell align="right">{row.price}</TableCell> */}
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
```

My theme palette:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#262626"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#323232"
    },
  }
});
```

I tried `styled()` to create a dark theme table but this also has same effect as above screenshot:

```
import React from "react";
import { TableContainer } from "@mui/material";
import { alpha, styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const CustomTable = styled(TableContainer)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: theme.palette.primary.main,
}));
export default function CustomTableContainer({ children }) {
  return <CustomTable>{children}</CustomTable>;
}
```

Does anyone know an easier way to make a dark theme table?

Answer (score 0):

In createTheme there is property named 'mode' if you set it to dark ,dark mode will be enabled

here you can see example https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/dark-mode/#ToggleColorMode.js

and you can set dark mode and light mode property for palette color to be changed on theme change

like this :

```
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#262626",
      dark: "#FFFFFF",
      light: "#000000",
    },
   }
```

https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/

Comment: Thanks man. I want to ask how to calculate the dark and light values if I have custom value for main?

Comment: my pleasure, that's depends on your ui, you can set whatever that fits better.